# How many sub-directories should be put into a directory

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

At SO there has been much discussion about how many files in a directory are appropriate: on older filesystems stay below a few thousand on newer stay below a few hundred thousand.
Generally the suggestion is to create sub-directories for every few thousand files.

So the next question is: what is the maximum number of sub directories I should put into a directory? Nesting them too deep kills dir tree traversal performance. IS there a nesting them to shallow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a practicality standpoint applications might not handle well large directory entries.
For example Windows Explorer gets bogged down with with several thousand directory entries (I've had Vista crash, but XP seems to handle it better).

Since you mention nesting directories also keep in mind that there are limits to the length of fully qualified (with drive designator and path) filenames [(See wikipedia 'filename' entry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename).  This will vary with the operating system file system [(See Wikipedia 'comparison on file systems' entry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems).

For Windows NTFS it is supposed to be 255, however, I have encountered problems with commands and API functions with fully qualified filenames at about 120 characters. I have also had problems with long path names on mapped networked drives (at least with Vista and I.E. Explorer 7).

Also there are limitations on the nesting level of subdirectories.  For example CD-ROM (ISO 9660) is limited to 8 directory levels (something to keep in mind if you would want to copy your directory structure to a CD-ROM, or another filesystem).

So there is a lot of inconsistency when you push the file system to extremes 
(while the file system may be able to handle it theoretically, apps and libraries may not).

Answer (score 2):

Really depends on the OS you are using as directory manipulations are done using system calls. For unix based OS, i-node look-up algorithms are highly efficient and number of files and folders in a directory does not matter. May be that's why there is no limit to it in Unix based systems. However, in windows, [it varies from file-system to file-systems](http://ask-leo.com/is_there_a_limit_to_what_a_single_folder_or_directory_can_hold.html).

Answer (score 1):

Usually modern filesystems (like NTFS or ext3) don't have a problem with accessing files directly (ie. if you are trying to open /foo/bar/baz.dat). Where you can run into problems is enumerating subdirectories / files in a given directory (ie. give me all the files/dirs from /foo). This can occur in multiple scenarios (for example while debugging, or during backup, etc). I found that keeping childcount around a couple of hundred at most gave me acceptable response times.

Of course this varies from situation to situation, so do test :-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is as little as possible.

At ISP I was working for (back in 2003) we had lots of user emails and web files. We structured them with md5 hashed usernames, 3 levels deep (ie. /home/a/b/c/abcuser). This resulted in maybe up to 100 users inside third level directory.

You can make deeper structure with user directories in shallow structure too. The best option is to try and see, but smaller the directory count faster the lookup is.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a similar situation recently. We were using the file system to store serialized trade details. These would only be looked at infrequently and it wasn't worth the pain to store them in a database.

We found that Windows and Linux coped with a thousand or so files but it did get much slower accessing them - we organised them in sub-dirs in a logical grouping and this solved the problem.

It was also easier to grep them. Grepping through thousands of files is slower than changing to the correct sub-dir and grepping through a few hundred.

Answer (score 1):

In windows API, the [maximum length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#maxpath) is set as 260 characters. The unicode functions do extend this limit to 32767 characters, which is used by major file systems.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the hard way that for UFS2 the limit is around 2^15 sub-directories. So while UFS2 and oder modern filesystems work decently with a few hundred thousand files in a directory it can only handle relatively few sub-directories. The non-obvious error message is "can't create link".

While I haven't tested ext2 I found various mailing list postings where the posters also had issues with more than 2^15 files on an ext2 filesystem.